# RStudio behaves in unexpected ways in Anaconda

Tags: rstudio, anaconda

The little red 'stop' button is disabled in my Anaconda-installed RStudio: I cannot use it to stop either a running Shiny app or dashboard and I cannot use it to interrupt `Sys.sleep(30)`. I already reported this to RStudio and they confirmed that this behavior is unexpected, [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115006375927-Shiny-apps-and-dashboards-won-t-stop). Has anybody else run into this? Any workarounds?

Comment: Does Anaconda have an issue tracker where this can be reported?

Comment: Google to the rescue. I submitted it -- https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1732.